# Azure OpenAI gpt-35-turbo nondeterministic with temperature 0

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, chatgpt-api, azure-openai

I have noticed that my deployment of gpt-35-turbo on "Azure AI Studio" is not giving consistent responses to my chat completion prompts even when I set the temperature to 0. The longer the prompt, the more inconsistency I see.

I thought the idea with setting temperature to 0 meant consistent (deterministic) responses (given the same model). Is that not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `temperature` parameter controls the *randomness* of the text generated and while a value of `0` ensures the **least** random or **more** deterministic responses, they will not necessarily be **exactly** the same.

Ideally, in cases where you would like deterministic responses (say for the same input across devices/users/etc.) then a response cache would help.

Also, while not recommended in the docs, you could also use the `top_p` parameter to further control the output response. This controls the set of possible tokens to consider for the next token.

[This discussion on the OpenAI forums](https://community.openai.com/t/cheat-sheet-mastering-temperature-and-top-p-in-chatgpt-api-a-few-tips-and-tricks-on-controlling-the-creativity-deterministic-output-of-prompt-responses/172683) goes into how you can use both to your benefit and better control the response from the models.

Comment: I saw the docs mentioned specifically not modifying top_p if I'm already modifying temperature. You're suggesting I set temp 0 and top_p to .1 to get the most consistent results?

Comment: @alex9311 are you getting consistent response?

Answer (score 4):

> I thought the idea with setting temperature to 0 meant consistent (deterministic) responses (given the same model). Is that not the case?

It's indeed not the case. 2 reasons:

1. [GPU non-determinism](https://community.openai.com/t/run-same-query-many-times-different-results/140588/4)
2. This [blogpost](https://152334h.github.io/blog/non-determinism-in-gpt-4/) authored by [Sherman Chann](https://linkedin.com/in/sherman-chann-385ab71a7) argues that "Non-determinism in GPT-4 is caused by Sparse MoE [mixture of experts]".

---

Note that since 2023-11-06, it is possible to set a seed parameter. From [platform.openai.com/docs](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/reproducible-outputs) ([mirror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqTsh.png)):

> Reproducible outputs (Beta)
>
> Chat Completions are non-deterministic by default (which means model outputs may differ from request to request). That being said, we offer some control towards deterministic outputs by giving you access to the [seed](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create#completions/create-seed) parameter and the [system_fingerprint](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/object#completions/object-system_fingerprint) response field.
>
> To receive (mostly) deterministic outputs across API calls, you can:
>
> - Set the [seed](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create#chat-create-seed) parameter to any integer of your choice and use the same value across requests you'd like deterministic outputs for.
> - Ensure all other parameters (like **`prompt`** or **`temperature`**) are the exact same across requests.
>
> Sometimes, determinism may be impacted due to necessary changes OpenAI makes to model configurations on our end. To help you keep track of these changes, we expose the [system_fingerprint](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/object#chat/object-system_fingerprint) field. If this value is different, you may see different outputs due to changes we've made on our systems.

Comment: Looks like, as of today (2023-11-10), the seed is not available on Azure OpenAI

Comment: @GamlielCohen Azure tends to lag behind for OpenAI model deployments and updates.